# How to return a value of the most recent document entry in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently I have a MongoDB with entries that look like this:

```
{
id: 62f49ecffd9375f8876dffab
channelId: "#username"
stockName: "$USERNAME"
stockPrice: 22
timestamp: "2022-08-11T06:16:47.817Z"
}
```

located in the database "testDB" and the collection "testColl".

What I am trying to do is find a way to be able to return the value of `stockPrice` in node.js. Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
     if(message === "!debug"){
        console.log(new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URL.concat(channel.toString().substring(1))).db(databaseName).collection(collectionName).find().sort('timestamp').limit(1));
     }
```

where `databaseName = "testDB"` and `collectionName = "testColl"`. I am quite new with MongoDB so not very familiar with its syntax. Currently when I call this code, I get:

```
node_modules/tmi.js/lib/logger.js:11
FindCursor {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, Symbol(kCapture): false, Symbol(client): MongoClient, …}
_events:
{}
_eventsCount:
0
_maxListeners:
undefined
client:
ƒ client() {\n        return this[kClient];\n    }
closed:
ƒ closed() {\n        return this[kClosed];\n    }
cursorOptions:
ƒ cursorOptions() {\n        return this[kOptions];\n    }
id:
ƒ id() {\n        return this[kId];\n    }
killed:
ƒ killed() {\n        return this[kKilled];\n    }
loadBalanced:
ƒ loadBalanced() {\n        var _a;\n        return !!((_a = this[kClient].topology) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.loadBalanced);\n    }
namespace:
ƒ namespace() {\n        return this[kNamespace];\n    }
readConcern:
ƒ readConcern() {\n        return this[kOptions].readConcern;\n    }
readPreference:
ƒ readPreference() {\n        return this[kOptions].readPreference;\n    }
server:
ƒ server() {\n        return this[kServer];\n    }
session:
ƒ session() {\n        return this[kSession];\n    }
Symbol(builtOptions):
{raw: false, promoteLongs: true, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false, ignoreUndefined: false, …}
Symbol(client):
MongoClient {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, s: {…}, Symbol(kCapture): false, …}
Symbol(closed):
false
Symbol(documents):
(0) []
Symbol(filter):
{}
Symbol(initialized):
false
Symbol(kCapture):
false
Symbol(killed):
false
Symbol(namespace):
MongoDBNamespace {db: 'testDB', collection: 'testColl'}
Symbol(options):
{readPreference: ReadPreference, fieldsAsRaw: {…}, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false, promoteLongs: true, …}
Symbol(session):
ClientSession {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, client: MongoClient, sessionPool: ServerSessionPool, …}
```

Also want to add, I may not need to sort my documents since the entries will always be in chronological order but I was trying to use `timestamp` to sort by the time the entry was placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot packed into a single line of code.  Let's break your console.log value up into several lines, so we can more easily see what's going on.

```
const channelName = channel.toString().substring(1);
const url = process.env.MONGO_URL.concat(channelName);
const client = new MongoClient(url);
const db = client.db(databaseName);
const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
const cursor = collection.find().sort('timestamp').limit(1);
```

You are logging `cursor`.

Looking at the [mongodb API documentation for node.js](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.8/), it looks like you are missing one or two things.

First, you never actually connect to the server (eg, by calling the [`connect()` method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.8/classes/MongoClient.html#connect)).  Now, I'm no mongo expert, and it may be that mongo does some cool just-in-time connect-if-not-connected magic when you call a method that requires a connection.  If such magic exists, then this is a red herring.
But, if not, you'll need to add an `await client.connect();` line in there.

Second, to get the value out of the cursor, you need to call a cursor method, like [`next()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.8/classes/FindCursor.html#next).  This returns a promise, so you'll need to `await` the promise in order to log the value.

```
async function getLatestStockPrice(channel, databaseName, collectionName) {
    const channelName = channel.toString().substring(1);
    const url = process.env.MONGO_URL.concat(channelName);
    const client = new MongoClient(url);
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db(databaseName);
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    const cursor = collection.find().sort('timestamp').limit(1);
    const item = await cursor.next();
    return item.stockPrice;
}
```